# What is actual concept of HATEOAS?

Tags: rest, restful-authentication, restful-architecture, hateoas

I read much about HATEOAS on many sites but still I'm confused about the concept. The basic definition of it is

**The browser doesn't know in advance where to submit the information, and it doesn't know in advance what information to submit. Both forms of information are entirely supplied by the serve**.

The concept is undefined or I'm not getting it?

Comment: Hypermedia As The Engine Of Application State is not a "defined" acronym, but part of Fielding's thesis on REST (which you probably are aware of if you have read about HATEOAS on the web). Take for instance a look at his famous rant: http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven. The client DOES know WHAT information to submit - but it relies on HATEOAS to tell it WHERE and HOW. I have tried to explain why hypermedia is such a good thing in this blog post: http://soabits.blogspot.com/2013/12/selling-benefits-of-hypermedia.html (there's a few more similar posts too).

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to have a client that knows very little about the server, except for the start address. This is how the web works -- when you go to Amazon.com you start shopping from that address, accessing resources and performing transactions without ever worrying about urls or possible transitions or datatypes. HATEOAS is the idea that web apps should all be built that way.